# Where's the Node.js root on Windows?

Tags: node.js

Here is my Node.js code (trying to console.log to a file):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');

var logFile = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/test', { flags: 'a' });

// Or 'w' to truncate the file every time the process starts.
var logStdout = process.stdout;

console.log = function () {
    logFile.write(util.format.apply(null, arguments) + '\n');
    logStdout.write(util.format.apply(null, arguments) + '\n');
}
console.error = console.log;
```

My issue: I can't find this mythical /tmp/test folder.

Comment: are you sure you're compiling it from the right place ?

Comment: Do `cd /tmp/` then do `ls` on terminal linux

Comment: @ArpitSolanki   why is it not giving me an error then ;/ ? what do you suggest I replace it with?  Everything else I try I get "Error: EACCES: permission denied, open './file.txt'
    at Error (native)"

Comment: Run your server with sudo permissions

Comment: @ArpitSolanki  please revert back your comment to the previous one :D (yes, I'm on Windows, not Linux!)

Comment: @SylvainAttoumani  What do you mean by "right place"? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That directory, `/tmp/test`, does not exist on Windows. It only exists on Linux. Replace it with a path that actually exist on Windows. like `C:/file.txt`.

You might want to check for permissions and path when you are creating a file.

Comment: So now, I get "Error: EACCES: permission denied".

Do you know the sudo equivalent on windows? I tried "runas" and "elevate" and they won't work in this case :/

thanks

Comment: Run as administrator is sudo equivalent for Windows. Also check that you have write permissions or not